# Serving images from a private repo using Github's Content API

Tags: image, next.js, github-api

I am working on a GitHub App that requires making images stored in a repository's `project/public` directory publicly accessible so that they can be used in static web pages (similar to the [NextJS "public" directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)).

For example, let's say I have a repository with `app/public/logo.png`. I would like to make `logo.png` available at images.domain.com/.../logo.png.

Now, there are a couple ways I know I can accomplish this:

1. Create an endpoint in my Node API where I can retrieve the `download_url` using the [Github Request Content API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content), then respond with the image buffer. As the documentation says though, "Download URLs expire and are meant to be used just once. To ensure the download URL does not expire, please use the contents API to obtain a fresh download URL for each download". This makes me worried about performance.
2. I can store the image in an external service (eg. S3). The downside of this approach is that the business logic becomes more complicated and I now need to pay for image hosting. Also, in the first approach everything lives inside of git, and the user 'owns' all their data.

So, I would like to go with the first option, but wanted to know:

- Is there another approach that I should be looking into?
- Are there obvious issues I am likely to run into with the first approach?

Comment: Hello Nicholas, what did you end up doing?